# Como guardar Json em local host via Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title> teste </title>
<body style="background-color: white">

  <form>
  Primeiro Nome: <input class="nome1" type="text" name="FirstName" value=""><br>
  Segundo Nome: <input  class="nome2" type="text" name="LastName" value=""><br>
  <input class="enviar" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

<script>


$(".enviar").click(function(){

  event.preventDefault();

  nome1 = $(".nome1").val();
  nome2 = $(".nome2").val();

  var banco = [
    {
    nome : nome1,
    sobrenome : nome2
  }
]

  console.log(banco);

  $.post("http://localhost:3000/teste", banco, function(){
    console.log("ok");
  });

});
```

estou com o erro server not response 404 ( not found )

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: E o que seria `http://localhost:3000/teste`? Alguma página servida pelo NodeJS?

Comment: Podes mostrar o código que tens no Node.js para tratar esse url?